# Convert string into array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Need to convert string into array of object in JavaScript. Here is the example,

```
var str = "1,2";
```

output:

```
"values":[
    {"id":"1"}, 
    {"id":"2"}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var str = "1,2"; 
var s = str.split(',').map(function(x){
   return {"id" : x};
})
str = {"values" : s};
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var str = "1,2";
    str = str.split(",");
    var obj = {'value':[]};
    str.forEach(function(val){
        obj.value.push({'id':val})
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "1,2"
var res = str.split(",");
values = []
for each (var item in res ) {
  values .push({
        id: item
    });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
```

use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) , `list push` and [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Both [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (for converting the string to an array) and `map` (which returns a *new* array for each element of the array that is passed through the provided function) are chainable so you can do the following:

```
var values = str.split(',').map(function (el) {
  return { id: el };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n78gnfgj/3/)

It's not clear whether you want just an array of objects, or a JSON string of that array. If it's the latter, use `JSON.stringify(result)`.